# How to improve performance of ORDER BY in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Hi I am having one table with approximately one billion rows. Doing ORDER BY on indexed field is taking around 3 seconds to fetch 30 records with LIMIT, whereas without ORDER BY it takes 195ms. I want to speed up this.

can anyone help me out with this ?

here is the simplified version of query (have removed some fields and few joins).

```
SELECT DISTINCT `auctions_opportunity`.`id`,
                `auctions_opportunity`.`employer_id`,
                `auctions_opportunity`.`salary`,
                `auctions_opportunity`.`is_active`,
                `auctions_opportunity`.`is_interested`,
                `auctions_opportunity`.`interview_status`,
                `auctions_opportunity`.`previous_interview_status`,
                `auctions_opportunity`.`creation_source`,
                `auctions_opportunity`.`created_at`,
                `auctions_opportunity`.`last_modified`,
                `auctions_opportunity`.`last_instant_alert_email_at`,
                `auctions_opportunity`.`last_daily_alert_email_at`,
                `auctions_opportunity`.`last_periodic_alert_email_at`,
                `auctions_opportunity`.`reviewed_at`,
                `auctions_opportunity`.`last_modified_by_id`,
                `auctions_opportunity`.`candidate_id`,
                `auctions_opportunity`.`job_id`,
                `auctions_opportunity`.`interview_request_notes`,
                `auctions_opportunity`.`application_email_at`,
                `auctions_opportunity`.`batch_application_email_at`,
                `auctions_opportunity`.`is_location_match`,
                `auctions_opportunity`.`is_strong_match`,
                `auctions_opportunity`.`score`,
                `auctions_opportunity`.`es_score`,
                `auctions_opportunity`.`message`,
                `auctions_opportunity`.`es_maybe`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`id`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`user_id`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`phone`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`is_new`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`last_seen`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`last_agreed_to_terms_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`email_backend_status`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`email_suppressed_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`email_verified_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`number_verified_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`last_emailed_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`last_updated`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`internal_note`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`main_skills`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`main_skills_nopunc`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`total_experience`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`current_company`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`current_company_nopunc`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`current_designation`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`onboarding_completed_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`previously_onboarded`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`talent_advocate_id`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`job_function_skills`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`availability`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`deactivated_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`deactivated_by_id`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`deactivation_source`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`is_private`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`previous_companies`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`companies_interned_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`gender`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`skype_id`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`alternate_phone`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`shadow_linkedin`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`last_job_post_email`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`last_job_alert_email`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`last_joining_email_sent`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`last_hired_email_sent`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`last_reonboarding_email`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`last_indexed_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`resume_viewed_notification_type`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`last_resume_viewed_email_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`seen_go_premium_modal_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`seen_active_check_modal_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`alerts_limit_reached_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`calculation_done_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`calculation_attempted_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`bio`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`last_seen_activity_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`job_unsubscribed_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`monthly_alerts_unsubscribed_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`resume_views_unsubscribed_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`update_preferences_unsubscribed_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`onboarding_reminder_unsubscribed_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`is_hireable`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`recruiter_message_push_unsubscribed_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`resume_views_email_unsubscribed_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`resume_views_push_unsubscribed_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`profile_reminder_email_unsubscribed_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`profile_reminder_push_unsubscribed_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`newsletter_email_unsubscribed_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`newsletter_push_unsubscribed_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`product_updates_email_unsubscribed_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`product_updates_push_unsubscribed_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`push_notifications_shown_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`push_notifications_enabled`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`push_notifications_verified_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`whatsapp_number`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`whatsapp_enabled`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`whatsapp_verified_at`,
                `candidates_candidate`.`last_whatsapp_sent_at`,
                `auth_user`.`id`,
                `auth_user`.`password`,
                `auth_user`.`last_login`,
                `auth_user`.`is_superuser`,
                `auth_user`.`username`,
                `auth_user`.`first_name`,
                `auth_user`.`last_name`,
                `auth_user`.`email`,
                `auth_user`.`is_staff`,
                `auth_user`.`is_active`,
                `auth_user`.`date_joined`
FROM `auctions_opportunity`
INNER JOIN `employers_employer` ON (`auctions_opportunity`.`employer_id` = `employers_employer`.`id`)
INNER JOIN `jobs_job` ON (`auctions_opportunity`.`job_id` = `jobs_job`.`id`)
INNER JOIN `profiles_profilestatus` ON (`employers_employer`.`status_id` = `profiles_profilestatus`.`id`)
INNER JOIN `candidates_candidate` ON (`auctions_opportunity`.`candidate_id` = `candidates_candidate`.`id`)
INNER JOIN `auth_user` ON (`candidates_candidate`.`user_id` = `auth_user`.`id`)
INNER JOIN `candidates_resume` ON (`candidates_candidate`.`id` = `candidates_resume`.`candidate_id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `candidates_jobsearchpreferences` ON (`candidates_candidate`.`id` = `candidates_jobsearchpreferences`.`candidate_id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `candidates_customaction` ON (`auctions_opportunity`.`id` = `candidates_customaction`.`opportunity_id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `candidates_emailaction` ON (`auctions_opportunity`.`id` = `candidates_emailaction`.`opportunity_id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `candidates_saveaction` ON (`auctions_opportunity`.`id` = `candidates_saveaction`.`opportunity_id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `candidates_hideaction` ON (`auctions_opportunity`.`id` = `candidates_hideaction`.`opportunity_id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `candidates_hireaction` ON (`auctions_opportunity`.`id` = `candidates_hireaction`.`opportunity_id`)
WHERE (`auctions_opportunity`.`employer_id` = 4
       AND NOT (`auctions_opportunity`.`job_id` IS NULL)
       AND `profiles_profilestatus`.`name` = Approved
       AND NOT (`auth_user`.`email` = deactivated@blobinfotech.com)
       AND NOT (`candidates_candidate`.`availability` = 3)
       AND NOT (`auctions_opportunity`.`job_id` IS NULL)
       AND NOT (`candidates_resume`.`id` IS NULL)
       AND (`jobs_job`.`is_active` = TRUE
            AND `auctions_opportunity`.`is_active` = TRUE)
       AND ((((`candidates_candidate`.`is_hireable` = TRUE
               AND `candidates_candidate`.`last_seen` >= 2020-12-18 09:19:42.873898
               AND `candidates_jobsearchpreferences`.`status` = 0)
              OR (`candidates_candidate`.`is_hireable` = TRUE
                  AND (NOT (`candidates_jobsearchpreferences`.`status` = 0)
                       OR (`candidates_candidate`.`last_seen` < 2020-12-18 09:19:42.873989
                           AND `candidates_jobsearchpreferences`.`status` = 0))))
             AND `candidates_candidate`.`is_private` = FALSE)
            OR `auctions_opportunity`.`interview_status` = 1
            OR NOT (`auctions_opportunity`.`id` IN
                      (SELECT U0.`id` AS Col1
                       FROM `auctions_opportunity` U0
                       LEFT OUTER JOIN `candidates_emailaction` U1 ON (U0.`id` = U1.`opportunity_id`)
                       WHERE (U1.`reply_email_at` IS NULL
                              AND U0.`id` = (`auctions_opportunity`.`id`)))))
       AND NOT (`auctions_opportunity`.`candidate_id` IN
                  (SELECT U2.`candidate_id` AS Col1
                   FROM `candidates_blockedemployerintermediate` U2
                   WHERE U2.`employer_id` = 4))
       AND `auctions_opportunity`.`job_id` IN (40729)
       AND NOT (((`auctions_opportunity`.`creation_source` = 8
                  AND `auctions_opportunity`.`creation_source` IS NOT NULL)
                 OR (`auctions_opportunity`.`interview_status` = 1
                     AND `auctions_opportunity`.`is_active` = FALSE)))
       AND ((((`candidates_candidate`.`is_hireable` = TRUE
               AND (NOT (`candidates_jobsearchpreferences`.`status` = 0
                         AND `candidates_jobsearchpreferences`.`status` IS NOT NULL)
                    OR (`candidates_candidate`.`last_seen` < 2020-12-18 09:19:42.863410
                        AND `candidates_jobsearchpreferences`.`status` = 0)))
              OR (`candidates_candidate`.`is_hireable` = TRUE
                  AND `candidates_jobsearchpreferences`.`status` = 2))
             AND `candidates_candidate`.`is_private` = FALSE
             AND `auctions_opportunity`.`interview_status` = 0
             AND (`auctions_opportunity`.`is_location_match` = TRUE
                  OR ((`candidates_jobsearchpreferences`.`current_location` LIKE %Delhi%
                       OR `candidates_jobsearchpreferences`.`current_location` LIKE %Noida%
                       OR `candidates_jobsearchpreferences`.`current_location` LIKE %Gurgaon%
                       OR `candidates_jobsearchpreferences`.`current_location` LIKE %Faridabad%
                       OR `candidates_jobsearchpreferences`.`current_location` LIKE %Greater Noida%)
                      AND (`jobs_job`.`locations` LIKE %Delhi%
                           OR `jobs_job`.`locations` LIKE %Noida%
                           OR `jobs_job`.`locations` LIKE %Gurgaon%
                           OR `jobs_job`.`locations` LIKE %Faridabad%
                           OR `jobs_job`.`locations` LIKE %Greater Noida%)
                      AND `jobs_job`.`accept_outstation` = FALSE)))
            OR (((`candidates_candidate`.`is_hireable` = TRUE
                  AND (NOT (`candidates_jobsearchpreferences`.`status` = 0
                            AND `candidates_jobsearchpreferences`.`status` IS NOT NULL)
                       OR (`candidates_candidate`.`last_seen` < 2020-12-18 09:19:42.863410
                           AND `candidates_jobsearchpreferences`.`status` = 0)))
                 OR (`candidates_candidate`.`is_hireable` = TRUE
                     AND `candidates_jobsearchpreferences`.`status` = 2))
                AND `auctions_opportunity`.`reviewed_at` < 2020-12-18 09:19:42.863329
                AND `auctions_opportunity`.`interview_status` = 1))
       AND `auctions_opportunity`.`employer_id` = 4
       AND `candidates_customaction`.`id` IS NULL
       AND `candidates_emailaction`.`id` IS NULL
       AND `candidates_saveaction`.`id` IS NULL
       AND (`candidates_hideaction`.`id` IS NULL
            OR `candidates_hideaction`.`is_deleted` = TRUE)
       AND `candidates_hireaction`.`id` IS NULL
       AND `auctions_opportunity`.`employer_id` = 4)
ORDER BY `auctions_opportunity`.`reviewed_at` DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: Do you use offset too with your limit? Can you share your actual query and your indexes?

Comment: Do you have index(es) on your ORDER BY COLUMN(s) ?

Comment: Please include the query, or even better, a simplified version of it.

Comment: edited the question with query

Comment: Please share your schema, and show the output from `EXPLAIN ...`.

Comment: The query is invalid. You are accessing tables you don't select from (candidates_candidate, auth_user) and there are parentheses where they don't belong. As to your problem: Sorting can be an expensive operation. Especially on a large data set. How many rows would you get without the limit clause? How many rows would you get without `LIMIT` and without `DISTINCT`? Is `DISTINCT` really necessary?

Comment: It's not the `ORDER BY`. It's the joins. When the query doesn't need ordering the engine does not need to perform comprehensive joins; when you add the ordering the engine needs to [partially/fully] walk the joins. I would suggest you index the joining columns as well.

Comment: Please try `select count(*) from ...`. This gives us an idea of the volume that must be sorted. Also: How long does it take to count all rows? Sorting is much more time consuming than just counting. Maybe this query can't get faster. Maybe you can limit the intermediate result set before sorting or maybe even before joining all tables. This is hard to guess though, without seeing your complete query, knowing your data and what the query is supposed to do.

Comment: Without the `ORDER BY`, the result will be different, unless you are lucky. Without the order by only the first records that are found are returned, and that need to be the 30 highest values for `auctions_opportunity.reviewed_at`

Comment: What table is `Approved` in?  Please qualify each column involved in any JOIN.

Comment: I see `candidates_jobsearchpreferences.status`, but I don't see `JOIN candidates_jobsearchpreferences` -- What gives??  Ditto for `U0` and `U1`.

Comment: updated the query

Answer (score 1):

While it may seem like the `ORDER BY` is to blame, it may well be other things causing poor performance.

- `OR` in `WHERE` and `ON` should be avoided where practical.
- `NOT x IN ( SELECT ... )` should be turned into either `NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ... )` or `LEFT JOIN ( SELECT y ... ) ... WHERE y IS NULL`
- Some possible indexes to help:

  ```
    auctions_opportunity:  INDEX(employer_id, interview_status, job_id)
    candidates_saveaction:  INDEX(opportunity_id, id)
    profiles_profilestatus:  INDEX(name)
    candidates_jobsearchpreferences:  INDEX(status)
    U1:  INDEX(reply_email_at)
  ```

**Based on big version of query**

- The 6 `LEFT JOINs` that constitute part of the filtering are probably part of the performance problem.  Can the column being tested be moved into the main table?
- There about two dozen `ORs`.  Each inhibits the possibility of an index on whatever is being tested.  For most of them, I don't have a constructive suggestion.
- `status = 0` implies `status IS NOT NULL`.  I suspect some of the complex boolean expressions can be simplified.
- Having a column that could be either `NULL` or `0`, but interpreting those two 'values' leads to unnecessarily complex queries.  Pick either `NULL` or `0`, then map both to the picked value as the data is being inserted.
- There are redundant tests such as `AND  NOT (`auctions_opportunity`.`job_id `IS NULL)`.  Sure, the Optimizer *might* filter out the extra effort, but let's not trust it.
- Can the flags `is_hireable`, `is_private`, `availability` be combined in some way that both makes the query simpler and still provides the details?
- `AND NOT (`auth_user`.`email `= deactivated@blobinfotech.com)` is a syntax error -- are there other errors?  (Quotes missing)
- Instead of several `LIKE '%...%'`, a single `RLIKE '...|...'` would probably be faster.
- Do you need `candidates_resume`?  It does not seem to be used.
- The use of `U1` seems strange.  The `LEFT JOIN` is `ON opportunity_id`, yet the `IS NULL` test is on a different column (`reply_email_at`).  This may not work as you expect.
- Some of the following indexes may help.

  ```
    auctions_opportunity:  INDEX(employer_id, job_id, reviewed_at)
    jobs_job:  INDEX(is_active, locations, accept_outstation, id)
    profiles_profilestatus:  INDEX(name, id)
    candidates_jobsearchpreferences:  INDEX(candidate_id, status, current_location, candidate_id)
    blobinfotech:  INDEX(com)
    U1:  INDEX(opportunity_id, reply_email_at)
    U2:  INDEX(employer_id,  candidate_id)
  ```
- Change

  ```
              AND  NOT (`auctions_opportunity`.`candidate_id` IN (
                        SELECT  U2.`candidate_id` AS Col1
                            FROM  `candidates_blockedemployerintermediate` U2
                            WHERE  U2.`employer_id` = 4)
                       )
  ```

to

```
     AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 
              FROM `candidates_blockedemployerintermediate` U2
              WHERE `auctions_opportunity`.`candidate_id` =  U2.`candidate_id`
                AND  U2.`employer_id` = 4 )
```

Comment: I've updated the question with actual query being used. can you please look at once again ? earlier I've removed few fields and joins just make it smaller but I guess that was my mistake

Comment: I adjusted the INDEXes some, plus added a few bullet items.

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is rather easy. If you take a telephone book and are asked to name thirty telephone numbers (`LIMIT 30` without an `ORDER BY`) where the person's street name contains an A, how long would that take you? A few minutes probably. Now, you are asked to name the thirty *lowest* telephone numbers (`LIMIT 30` with an `ORDER BY`) where the person's street name contains an A. You'll have to read the whole book, pick out all numbers where the street name matches, then sort all entries by number and then take the first thirty. How long will that take in comparison?

So, it's not at all surprising that you see a significant difference with and without using `ORDER BY`. It's expected.

In your case the DBMS may just pick rows with `is_location_match = TRUE` and thus avoid the costly location searches with `LIKE` for instance (if this suffices to find 30 rows in the end). It can't do so, when it must consider all matches in order to find your *top* 30 rows specified by `ORDER BY`.

Back to the telephone book: If the telephone book has only 50 entries, the job won't be too hard. If it has a million entries, searching it will take ages. So it must be our objective to deal with a small data set. You are joining the table `candidates_resume` without using it. (The condition `AND NOT candidates_resume.id IS NULL` is superfluous and makes no sense.) You are also joining all `candidates_hideaction` rows where `is_deleted = TRUE`. Let's say there are three resumes and five deleted hide actions per candidate. Thus you are blowing up your data set by the factor of 15 (3 x 5) only to dismiss the duplicates later with `DISTINCT`. `DISTINCT` is a very costly operation on large data sets. It is also a typical indicator for a badly written query, as in your case: It is unnecessary joins that blow up your intermediate result, and rather than fixing the join problem you are applying `DISTINCT` in the end.

You are also using many anti joins (e.g. `LEFT OUTER JOIN candidates_customaction` ... `WHERE candidates_customaction.id IS NULL`). This had me confused at first. I wondered why you are cross joining all those candidate actions until I found the `IS NULL` conditions. I consider these anti joins not readable. And now let's say that there ten actions for each of the four anti-joined action types per candidate. If the DBMS does the join, it will create 10000 (10 x 10 x 10 x 10) rows for a single candidate that must all get dismissed. I'd opt for `NOT EXISTS` clauses instead to get this more readable and maybe avoid an unnecessarily large intermediate result. I'd use `NOT EXISTS` for the check for undeleted hide actions, too.

Having said this, my recommendation is that you change the query such that you can dismiss `DISTINCT`. This can save the DBMS a lot of work and may show in the final execution speed.

There are some minor things you could do to get the query more readable. You don't have to state it thrice that you want `employer_id = 4` :-) Then, `status = 0 AND status IS NOT NULL` is just `status = 0` of course. And `NOT (status = 0 AND status IS NOT NULL) OR (last_seen < xxx AND status = 0)` is hence just `status <> 0 OR last_seen < xxx`. This won't speed up the query, but it will make it more readable and maintainable, and maybe you even wanted to consider status NULL and made a mistake that gets more obvious in the process of cleaning the conditions up.